# How to handle <article tag> in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I tried to find xpath for toggle button and the code shows as below.  but its throwing error as no such element

[image]

i entered the following code.  I checked for frame content also.  but its not even frame content

`w.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated (By.className(".slds-checkbox_faux"))).click();`

Comment: based on the image you included there is not element with a class of `slds-checkbox_faux`. So it is unclear what element you are actually trying to find.

Comment: Please can you clarify more that wher exactly you want to click? because, regarding the image there is not such element. also, please share code as text, not image.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, copy your code into the question with block code format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask